# Use a TRRS aux port as analog video output

Tags: laptop, audio, video, phone, analog

I found a 4 pin (TRRS) aux cable lying around with 3 RCA outputs (video and 2 channel audio. It was originally made for a Xbox 360. This got me to wondering: Would I be able to have video output through this cable from my phone (Galaxy S6 Edge) or even my laptop which has a TRRS port. I have tried this with my phone with no video output, however, can output sound as it would to normal headphones. If that is not possible since it is capable of outputting audio, would I be able to send an analog video signal as an audio signal, and connect the audio output as a video input. I would assume this would be possible at least from my laptop. I just have no idea on how I would go about achieving this. My laptop is running Windows 10 dual booted with Ubuntu. My phone is rooted running Android Marshmellow.

Comment: *"would I be able to send an analog video signal as an audio signal"* -- That makes no sense.  *"connect the audio output as a video input."* -- That makes no sense either.  An audio signal has 20KHz bandwidth, whereas  CVBS (aka composite) video requires 4 MHz.  Almost any arbitrary signal can be "played" through an audio system, but a CVBS signal is highly structured to display raster lines and video fields/frames. *"I would assume this would be possible at least from my laptop."* -- You assume incorrectly.

Comment: Same connector != same connection.

Comment: Alright, that sucks. Thanks for clarifying that for me.